# How to express a function type that depends on the value of other property

Tags: typescript

In a React project I have an `onChange` handler that is a function taking one argument.
The type of the argument can be a string or a string array, depending on another boolean property (`multiSelect`)

I was trying to express it like this:

```
type MultiSelect = {
  multiSelect: boolean;
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
};

type SingleSelect = {
  multiSelect?: false;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
};

type Select = SingleSelect | MultiSelect;

type Props = {otherStuff: string} & Select;
```

but this way typescript says that the type of the argument is `string & string[]` and gives me an error when I try to use it:

```
if (multiSelect) {
   onChange(['a', 'b']);
} else {
   onChange('c');
}
```

I get this error for the first branch:
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string & string[]'.

and this for the second branch:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & string[]'.

Comment: Why not just always pass an array? `onChange(['c'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Represent your `Props` as a union and make sure you're not destructuring `props` too early — if you destructure `props`, the relationships you have expressed by using a union are no longer preserved.

A working example:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = (
  | { multiSelect: true; onChange: (value: string[]) => void }
  | { multiSelect: false; onChange: (value: string) => void }
) & { otherStuff: string };

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = props => {
  if (props.multiSelect) {
    props.onChange(['foo', 'bar']);
  } else {
    props.onChange('foo')
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) and [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in Typescript to achieve what you want to achieve

```
 function onChange<T extends boolean>(input: T extends true ? string[] : string) : any {
        console.log(input)
    }
    
    onChange<true>(['a', 'b'])
    onChange<false>("a")
```